# Display average for every column at the bottom of the query

Tags: oracle

I need your help. 
Can you help me write a query that outputs the averages? 
I have 3 items - GAO, GAD and GAM and for every item 
I need to count average in the bottom of table, below "ALL". 
Query:

```
SELECT NVL(vrz.DATA, 'ALL') AS DAY,
SUM(vrz.SOV_GAO_1_ILE) AS GAO,
SUM(vrz.SOV_GAD_2_ILE) AS GAD,
SUM(vrz.SOV_GAM_3_ILE) AS GAM,
SUM(vrz.SOV_GAO_1_ILE) + SUM(vrz.SOV_GAD_2_ILE) + SUM(vrz.SOV_GAM_3_ILE) AS SUMMARY,
FLOOR((SUM(vrz.SOV_GAO_1_ILE) + SUM(vrz.SOV_GAD_2_ILE) + 
SUM(vrz.SOV_GAM_3_ILE))/3) AS AVERAGE
FROM PLC.V_RAPORT_ZDARZEN vrz
GROUP BY ROLLUP (vrz.DATA)
```

Part of data:

```
DAY         GAO     GAD     GAM   SUMMARY   AVERAGE
2017-05-25  1035,0  725,0   0,0   1760,0    586,0
2017-05-26  253,0   785,0   0,0 1038,0  346,0
2017-05-29  1060,0  467,0   0,0 1527,0  509,0
2017-05-30  922,0   905,0   0,0 1827,0  609,0
2017-05-31  1113,0  1343,0  0,0 2456,0  818,0
2017-06-01  1236,0  1057,0  0,0 2293,0  764,0
2017-06-02  1740,0  1182,0  0,0 2922,0  974,0
2017-06-04  22,0    1,0 0,0 23,0    7,0
2017-06-05  1702,0  1534,0  0,0 3236,0  1078,0
2017-06-06  1754,0  1388,0  0,0 3142,0  1047,0
2017-06-07  865,0   1109,0  0,0 1974,0  658,0
2017-06-08  1248,0  1044,0  0,0 2292,0  764,0
2017-06-09  752,0   978,0   0,0 1730,0  576,0
2017-06-12  1403,0  534,0   0,0 1937,0  645,0
2017-06-13  2415,0  850,0   0,0 3265,0  1088,0
2017-06-14  1159,0  458,0   0,0 1617,0  539,0
2017-06-16  361,0   372,0   0,0 733,0   244,0
2017-06-19  1605,0  393,0   0,0 1998,0  666,0
2017-06-20  938,0   694,0   0,0 1632,0  544,0
2017-06-21  2212,0  952,0   0,0 3164,0  1054,0
2017-06-22  1912,0  922,0   0,0 2834,0  944,0
2017-06-23  1030,0  1003,0  0,0 2033,0  677,0
2017-06-26  528,0   111,0   0,0 639,0   213,0
2017-06-27  910,0   485,0   0,0 1395,0  465,0
2017-06-28  708,0   240,0   0,0 948,0   316,0
2017-06-29  1819,0  1122,0  0,0 2941,0  980,0
.......
2017-11-03  809,0   585,0   600,0   1994,0  664,0
2017-11-06  953,0   1474,0  595,0   3022,0  1007,0
2017-11-07  800,0   1250,0  991,0   3041,0  1013,0
2017-11-08  0,0     615,0   1014,0  1629,0  543,0
ALL         131029,0    124262,0    112195,0    367486,0    122495,0
```

Averages:
`GAO         GAD         GAM 
    1082,884298 1027,834711 927,231405`

Thanks for your help!

[Picture that illustrates my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqwCW.jpg)

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Please don't paste pictures. Provide data and code as formatted text.

Comment: I updated post - just look :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rollup` is OK, but in this case I would use [CTE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2077142) and add two summary rows using `union all`.

```
with cte as (
    select data, count(1) cnt,
           sum(sov_gao_1_ile) gao, sum(sov_gad_2_ile) gad, sum(sov_gam_3_ile) gam,
           sum(sov_gao_1_ile + sov_gad_2_ile + sov_gam_3_ile) / 3 average
      from vrz
      group by data)
select to_char(data, 'yyyy-mm-dd') data, gao, gad, gam, gao+gad+gam summary, average 
  from cte
union all 
select 'ALL', sum(gao), sum(gad), sum(gam), sum(gao+gad+gam), sum(average)
  from cte
union all
select 'AVG', round(avg(gao)), round(avg(gad)), round(avg(gam)), null, null
  from cte
  order by 1
```

As I understand, You want averages from already grouped data, which can differ from average from the whole set. If not then @Wernfried's solution should work for You. 
Anyway you can use column `cnt` to divide sums by counts. In future please provide complete data and matching output, this way we can verify results.

Unions works on aggreated sums, so it should not impact performance. Simplified demo data and output:

```
with vrz(data, sov_gao_1_ile, sov_gad_2_ile, sov_gam_3_ile) as (
    select date '2000-01-21', 111, 112, 114 from dual union all
    select date '2000-01-21', 115, 116, 125 from dual union all
    select date '2000-01-22', 211, 212, 213 from dual union all
    select date '2000-01-22', 215, 216, 223 from dual union all
    select date '2000-01-23', 301, 302, 225 from dual),
cte as (
    select data, count(1) cnt,
           sum(sov_gao_1_ile) gao, sum(sov_gad_2_ile) gad, sum(sov_gam_3_ile) gam,
           sum(sov_gao_1_ile + sov_gad_2_ile + sov_gam_3_ile) / 3 average
      from vrz
      group by data)
select to_char(data, 'yyyy-mm-dd') data, gao, gad, gam, gao+gad+gam summary, average 
  from cte
union all 
select 'ALL', sum(gao), sum(gad), sum(gam), sum(gao+gad+gam), sum(average) 
  from cte
union all
select 'AVG', round(avg(gao)), round(avg(gad)), round(avg(gam)), null, null 
  from cte
  order by 1



DATA              GAO        GAD        GAM    SUMMARY    AVERAGE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2000-01-21        226        228        239        693        231
2000-01-22        426        428        436       1290        430
2000-01-23        301        302        225        828        276
ALL               953        958        900       2811        937
AVG               318        319        300
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be this one:

```
SELECT NVL(vrz.DATA, 'ALL') AS DAY,
   SUM(vrz.SOV_GAO_1_ILE) AS GAO,
   SUM(vrz.SOV_GAD_2_ILE) AS GAD,
   SUM(vrz.SOV_GAM_3_ILE) AS GAM,
   SUM(vrz.SOV_GAO_1_ILE) + SUM(vrz.SOV_GAD_2_ILE) + SUM(vrz.SOV_GAM_3_ILE) AS SUMMARY,
   FLOOR((SUM(vrz.SOV_GAO_1_ILE) + SUM(vrz.SOV_GAD_2_ILE) + SUM(vrz.SOV_GAM_3_ILE))/3) AS AVERAGE
FROM PLC.V_RAPORT_ZDARZEN vrz
GROUP BY ROLLUP (vrz.DATA)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AVG', 
   AVG(vrz.SOV_GAO_1_ILE),
   AVG(vrz.SOV_GAD_2_ILE),
   AVG(vrz.SOV_GAM_3_ILE),
   NULL, NULL
FROM PLC.V_RAPORT_ZDARZEN vrz;
```

However, it might be not the best solution in terms of performance.

Comment: This doesn't work properly becauce average is not good.
    GAO = 1082,884298
    GAD = 1027,834711
    GAM = 927,231405
These are averages for every item...

Comment: What do you mean by "is not good"? Please describe your requirements better.

Comment: @PonderStibbons shows the best solution, your average was not properly calculated.. :)